# Personalizar mensagem pela hora

Tags: c#, .net

Queria personalizar a mensagem de saudação dependendo da hora.

Ex:

```
Hora menor que 12h.
"Bom dia"

Hora menor que 18h.
"Boa tarde"
```

Fiz com `if` e `else` mas queria um método melhor.

```
//Pegando a hora
int hora = DateTime.Now.Hour;

#region saudação
//Personalizando a saudação
if (hora <= 11)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bom dia " + nome + "!");
}
else if (hora <= 17)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Boa tarde {nome}!");
}
else if (hora <= 23)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Boa noite {nome}!");
}
else if (hora <= 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Boa madrugada {nome}!");
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Qual o problema em usar if-else?
não há nada de errado nem que precise ser melhorado no seu código. 
Substituir por Switch case não vai melhorar a legibilidade.

Comment: Seu código contém uma falha, do jeito que você implementou, ele nunca irá exibir "Boa Madrugada", qnd for entre as 00 e as 5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
using System;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        int hora = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        var nome = "João";
        var saudacoes = new string[] { "Boa madrugada", "Bom dia", "Boa tarde", "Boa noite" };
        Console.WriteLine($"{saudacoes[hora / 6]} {nome}!");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/71SL1N). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oy4AqN). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/TextArray.cs).

Comment: Não tinha visto sua resposta antes, apesar de gostar, eu tenho uma leve impressão de que o AP vai usar a ideia sem entender como funciona =D Claro que isso não é problema seu (nem meu), é só um comentário mesmo.

Comment: Entendi.
Criou um array
[0] Boa madrugada
[1] Bom dia
[2] Boa tarde
[3] Boa noite

Divide a hora por 6 e imprime o array que pode ser de 0-3.